# How pass 2 parameters to EventEmitter in Angular?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have in my component an `EventEmitter` but I can't compile it because it throws the error:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

My component:

```ts
@Output() addModel = new EventEmitter<any>();

saveModel($event, make, name) {
  this.addModel.emit(make, name);
}
```

If I delete one of the parameters in `this.addModel.emit()` it works but is it possible to pass 2 parameters to `EventEmitter` and how?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

If you look at the [EventEmitter emit method @ angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter), it can only take a single parameter of type `T`

> emit(value?: T)

Since only a single parameter is allowed, consider passing it as an `object` in `emit` method.

In the snippet below, `make` & `name` variables are holding their respective values:

```js
this.addModel.emit({make: make, name: name});
//shorthand is below
this.addModel.emit({make, name});
```

Comment: Oh, ok, Thankyou! it will this.addModel.emit({make:make, name:name});

Comment: @echonax no need to do that, es6 will take care of it [check here](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/)

Comment: how can i observe/ take this value in parent component?

Comment: @roshini please take a look at how [component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) happens, basically you need to emit data from child component to parent component using `EventEmitter` object..

Comment: thanks for your response, i know this emitter between components but need interaction as passing data from directive to component..

Comment: please give better example? what is make and name?

Comment: @user1034912 may I know reason behind the answer? This answer is explanation based on whatever OP have been asked. If you don't understand. consider open a new question. Though I updated my answer, so that you could understand ES6 shorthand syntax. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Or else you can pass it as an array this.addModel.emit( [make, name] )

Comment: @PankajParkar I like the idea of strongly typing the object, but is there a way to make the input function receive a strongly typed object instead of an 'any' type? specifically just two strings in my case.

Comment: @S.Cannon can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 89):

Another option to strongly type it is as follows:

`@Output addModel = new EventEmitter<{make: string, name: string}>();`

you can then emit it like @Pankaj-Parkar shows

`this.addModel.emit({make, name});`
or
`this.addModel.emit({make: 'honda', name: 'civic'});`

You now have strong typing instead of using `object` or `any`.

Comment: This is the correct and complete solution, because it keeps the type of the arguments all the way through to the listener, which can also be strongly typed.

Comment: is there a way to make the input strongly typed too on the receiving component? I'd ideally want the function that takes the emitted event to force a object of two strings to be received, rather than a type 'any'. How would you do that?

Comment: @S.Cannon, I'm fairly new to Angular/TypeScript but I just tried this syntax as a function argument type (like `foo(event: {make: string, name: string})`) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 25):

I fixed it by making

```
EventEmitter<object>();
```

Then I was able to pass an object such as:

```
this.MyOutputVariable.emit({ name: 'jack', age: '12' });
```

And it worked.

Comment: This is great, Adham. Nothing against your answer, but it is worth noting that a standard practice -- and a good practice -- is to always supply an *Event Object in tandem with 1 or more values*: `publish(event, value)` & `subscribe(e, value) {...}`. I'm a little surprised that Angular defined their interface / implemented this the way they did.

Comment: Downvoted in favor of strongly types solutions like `new EventEmitter<{name: string, age: number}>();`

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old Question
for me I would create an interface and send it as an object where I can have my code more organized

```
 export interface addModelArgs{
      make:string,
      name:string
    }
@Output() addModel = new EventEmitter<addModelArgs>();
```

and call it as following

```
    this.addModel.emit({make: 'honda', name: 'civic'});
or 
    let savParamters:addModelArgs={make: 'honda', name: 'civic'};

    this.addModel.emit(savParamters);
```