# Taking two variable from parent component to child component

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am trying to send two variable from child component to the parent component

**I have placed the child selector to the  parent component view** , where I used child tag and bind the @output name myOutput to the getData function in the parent component and passed the event handler to it

```
<app-form-test [myInput]='myInputString' (myOutput)="getData($event)"></app-form-test>
```

**parent ts file =>**

```
  getData(value) {
    alert(value);
  }
```

**child ts file**

```
export class FormTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myInput: [];

  @Output() myOutput: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  firstOutputString = 'hello I am coming from child component'
  secondOutputString = " I am second string";

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  SendData() {
    this.myOutput.emit(this.firstOutputString);
  }
 }
```

Here I want to pass another variable secondOutputString to the parent component from child component I tried to pass it using

```
SendData() {
        this.myOutput.emit(this.firstOutputString , this.secondOutputString);
      }
```

But I am getting error

Comment: Soo what's the problem with the code?

Comment: you can emit not only an string else an object like {var1:"hello",var2:"word"}

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003639/how-pass-2-parameters-to-eventemitter-angular2

Answer (score 0):

in child .ts:

```
@Output() myOutput: EventEmitter<{firstOutputString: string, secondOutputString: string}> = new EventEmitter();

SendData() {
    this.myOutput.emit({
      firstOutputString: this.firstOutputString,
      secondOutputString: this.secondOutputString
    });
}
```

and in parent .ts:

```
getData(value) {
    console.log(value.firstOutputString);
    console.log(value.secondOutputString);
}
```